# SQL Rank() for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I have a set of data that stores employee and their takings for a period (a month say).  The data also stores multiple sites, and the employees can have takings for each site.  I am trying to add a rank to the data, so that each employee has a rank based on the takings, for each site.

**Example Data**

```
EmpId   Takings SiteID
1       150.00  1
1       0.00    2
2       0.00    1
2       100.00  2
3       100.00  1
3       1100.00 2
```

I have tried the below query but this only gives me ranks up to two:

```
SELECT EmpId,Takings,SiteID, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Takings DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM #test
```

This gives me the following result set:

```
EmpId   Takings SiteID  Rank
1       150.00  1       1
1       0.00    2       2
2       100.00  2       1
2       0.00    1       2
3       1100.00 2       1
3       100.00  1       2
```

I am expecting the following result set:

```
EmpId   Takings SiteID  Rank
1       150.00  1       1
1       0.00    2       3
2       100.00  2       2
2       0.00    1       3
3       1100.00 2       1
3       100.00  1       2
```

If I amend the Partition to include SiteId, then I get a rank of 1 for all employees.

What am I missing here, I am sure this should be a simple query, but it's killing me at the moment.

Thank You

Comment: As in the question the employees need to be ranked by takings at each site.  There are two rank 1's as there are multiple sites and each site should have a rank 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT EmpId,Takings,SiteID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SiteId ORDER BY Takings DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM #test
ORDER BY EmpId ASC, Takings DESC
```

Hopefully this one?

Comment: A i thought surprisingly simple.  I always trip up with Rank()

Comment: Yeah, first i was confused with your post, but then your final result made me realize, "i want to arrange things by SiteId and order the amount, then EmployeeId? uhh..not included in partition, but will be ordered later." yup, I think this is how I got this.

Answer (score 0):

By simply adding the SiteID to the partition worked for me

```
SELECT EmpId,
       Takings,
       SiteID,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, SiteID ORDER BY Takings DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM #test
```